# Randomly sampling subsets of dataframe variable

Tags: r, plyr

I am working on a large dataset which comprises travel behaviour data over a weekly period.  Over the course of a week, people have completed a log of the individual trips that they have taken place during that week.  Individuals are identified by a unique identification number (ID).  What I want to do is ramdonly choose two days of diary data (which may comprise one or many trips) from the weekly data that is available for each unique ID, and put this in a new data frame. An example data frame is detailed below:

```
Df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), 
                  date = c("1st Nov", "1st Nov", "3rd Nov", "4th Nov","4th Nov","5th Nov","2nd Nov", "2nd Nov", "3nd Nov", "4th Nov","5th Nov","5th Nov","2nd Nov", "2nd Nov", "3nd Nov", "4th Nov","5th Nov"))
```

Any help on the above would be gratefully received.

Many thanks,

Katie

Comment: Thanks for adding the example data, this makes it much easier to reply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a job for plyr. To sample two random days for each user:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(Df1, .(ID), function(x) {
  unique_days = as.character(unique(x$date))
  if(length(unique_days) < 2) {
    randomSelDays = unique_days
  } else {
    randomSelDays = sample(unique_days, 2)        
  }
  return(x[x$date %in% randomSelDays,])
})
```

This returns all the data for two selected days per unique identifier. In addition, if there is just one day for an ID, that day is returned. For example:

```
  ID    date
1  1 1st Nov
2  1 1st Nov
3  1 3rd Nov
4  2 3nd Nov
5  2 5th Nov
6  2 5th Nov
7  3 2nd Nov
8  3 2nd Nov
9  3 3nd Nov
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much for your help with the code - its so nearly right.  I probably didn't explain myself very well, but what I want to be left with is ALL the trips on TWO particular days - not just two trips out of the weekly data (so for some people that might leave two trips, for others, they could have gone on three journeys on one day, and two on the other).  For example person "1" in the orginal dataframe went on two trips on the 4th Nov, so this should be included in the second dataframe.

Comment: And you explained it well enough in the question, I just didn't read carefully enough :).

Comment: Just one more quick issue I am having with my data - for some ID numbers, I only have a data on a single day - how can I tweak the above code to say if there is only a single day, that is fine, and it can be incorporated the new data subset (along with the normal two selected days per unique identifer)? Code to follow below...

Comment: Df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,5), date = c("1st Nov", "1st Nov", "3rd Nov", "4th Nov","4th Nov","5th Nov","2nd Nov", "2nd Nov", "3rd Nov", "4th Nov","5th Nov", "5th Nov","2nd Nov", "2nd Nov", "3nd Nov", "4th Nov","5th Nov","3nd Nov","2nd Nov","2nd Nov"))

Comment: I updated the code, this should do the trick. If you like this answer, could you mark it is the correct answer (tick the green tick mark under the up/downvote icons).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5683/discussion-between-paul-hiemstra-and-katie-t)